# print found characters inside a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, find

Straight to the point: I am wanting to print every instance of these characters in a string. For example:

```
#Pseudocode below
animals = 'cat dog fish goat pig'
if 'abcd' in animals,
print(instanceOfIt)
```

would spit out
cada
*letters in `cat`, `dog` and `goat`
How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
animals = 'cat dog fish goat pig'
print(''.join(filter(lambda x: x in 'abcd', animals)))
```

`filter` takes a function and an iterable, and returns a new iterable that contains only those elements for which the function returned something truthy.

A lambda expression is like an inline function, it would be equivalent to writing `myfunction` there and defining it earlier like this:

```
def myfunction(x):
    return x in 'abcd'

print(''.join(filter(myfunction, animals)))
```

Alternatively (thanks, Peter Wood):

```
print(''.join(filter('abcd'.__contains__, animals)))
```

Comment: hmm... this seems to print out the entire string - like if there is a number it prints it.

Comment: So what would you want to print in your example?

Comment: cada - the instances of a, b, c, and d

Comment: @XXXX Misunderstood you, fixed.

Comment: can you explain what filter does, and what a lambda is

Comment: @XXXX I added explanations to my answer.

Comment: `filter('abcd'.__contains__, animals)`

Comment: `print(''.join(char for char in animals if char in set('abcd'))))`